# PHP CLI. Reading commands lines separated and save them to array till "exit" entered

Tags: php, command-line-interface

Suppose that you want to write a simple PHP script that will listen for command line input, and will allow the user to add an unknown number of arguments and save those argument to array (lets say `array_small`). This array (the `array_small`) will be saved in another array (lets call it `array_big`). Now the way to finish entering information is by typing "exit".
 
 
Example: User will enter the following in the command line:

```
Jack 20 30 40 30
John 30 40 20
Alex 50 30 1 1
exit
```

According to the example, the `array_big` will be something like this

```
[
 ['Jack', 20, 30, 40, 30], ['John', 30, 40, 20],...
]
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Web application that will listen for command line input? I cannot imagine such thing...

Comment: @mariobgr what web application? The title, the question and the tags clearly specify [CLI](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.introduction.php).

Comment: Have you tried reading [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php)? (Almost) everything is explained there.

Comment: This smells like homework or a job interview question.

Comment: @axiac - the question was about a web application in its first revision - it was obviously updated after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be lots of examples, but at the simplest:

```
$fh = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');
$array = array();

while($line = fgets($fh)) {
    if(trim($line) === 'exit') {
        break;
    }
    $array[] = explode(' ', $line);
}
print_r($array);
```

Comment: Don't forget to initialize your array

Comment: It's a good practice. In this particular example if your first input is "exit" this code will trigger a notice when executing `print_r($array)`.

Comment: Usage of uninitialized variables happens more often than you think, and can lead to unexpected results.

Comment: @s3v3n Nice catch - this is why I like collaborative coding

Comment: Also, if I'm not wrong, every last value in "small arrays" will contain the newline. So `$line` should be `trim`med every time.

Comment: And there's no need to use `fopen` since `STDIN` is an already opened stream to *stdin*. Well, my example covered them all...

Answer (score 0):

```
$lines = []; // or array() for PHP < 5.4

while ($line = trim(fgets(STDIN))) { // trim() to get read of newline
    if($line == 'exit') { break; }
    $lines[] = explode(' ', $line);
}
```